# RStudio shell move automatically from git-bash to cmd

Tags: r, git, shell, rstudio, git-bash

When I want to open the shell from within RStudio, the git-bash shell (MINGW64 ~) opens shortly and after a few second the shell windows automatically changes to the cmd shell (MSYS ~). The bash.exe is installed under C:\Program Files\Git\bin. I downloaded Git on another computer and the git-bash shell normally opens from RStudio.

Comment: I'm guessing that your (bash) `.profile` file is being silently and mysteriously (to you) executed, but you would need to be doing a thorough search of the factors that affect startup configuration. Seems more likely that this is a local bash configuration issue than an R issue. You should also look at the `.Rprofile` file in the $HOME directory when Rstudio is working on the afflicted computer. See `?Startup` (from an Rstudio session for the R specific details.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot find the .Rprofile file in the $HOME directory

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled RStudio and it is working fine. I still do not know what was the issue, but in similar case, I recommand to try reinstalling RStudio first.